# BeanCreationException not able create bean due to failed introspection in App Engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have deployed my spring boot application in App Engine, but it gives error that its not able create bean for my controller class

**Error I'm getting in GAE**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webAppController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [dev.jcodex.webapp.controller.WebAppController] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@4629104a]
at
dev.jcodex.webapp.WebappApplication.main (WebappApplication.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [dev.jcodex.webapp.controller.WebAppController] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@4629104a]
at
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:481)
at
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods (ReflectionUtils.java:321)
at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
 Show all
```

**My Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/profile")
public class WebAppController {

  //rest api methods
}
```

**Main Class**

```
SpringBootApplication
public class WebappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This error only occurs when I try to run in gae, but not during local execution

Comment: It looks like you might need to modify your pom.xml. Could you share your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually GCP App Engine standard env takes jdk version 8 or 9 only.
But I had project compiled in JDK 11 which I later changed to 9, now this created a problem on one of the Libraries `org.json.jsonexception`, i.e., during runtime No class found exception occurred causing this error to fall on Controller class which was using this library.